# What is the molarity of a solution made by dissolving 25.63 grams of naphthalene (MM = 128.17g) in 250.0 grams of benzene?

Tags: solubility, concentration

I don't really understand how to find the amount of liters with benzene in order to find the molarity.

Comment: Do you know how to find the number of moles of naphthalene in 25.63g ?

Comment: Question wasn't framed correctly. You need to know the density, either must be given in question or remembered beforehand